# Can I use non latin characters in my robots.txt and sitemap.xml?

Tags: sitemap, robots.txt, domain-name, punycode

Can I use non latin characters in my robots.txt file and sitemap.xml like this?

**robots.txt**

```
User-agent: *
Disallow: /somefolder/

Sitemap: http://www.domainwithåäö.com/sitemap.xml
```

**sitemap.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<urlset xmlns="http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9">
<url><loc>http://www.domainwithåäö.com/</loc></url>
<url><loc>http://www.domainwithåäö.com/subpage1</loc></url>
<url><loc>http://www.domainwithåäö.com/subpage2</loc></url>
</urlset>
```

Or should I do like this?

**robots.txt**

```
User-agent: *
Disallow: /somefolder/

Sitemap: http://www.xn--domainwith-z5al6t.com/sitemap.xml
```

**sitemap.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<urlset xmlns="http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9">
<url><loc>http://www.xn--domainwith-z5al6t.com/</loc></url>
<url><loc>http://www.xn--domainwith-z5al6t.com/subpage1</loc></url>
<url><loc>http://www.xn--domainwith-z5al6t.com/subpage2</loc></url>
</urlset>
```

Answer (score 1):

On https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/183668 Google writes: "Make sure that your URLs follow the RFC-3986 standard for URIs, the RFC-3987 standard for IRIs", so I guess the correct answer is that you have to follow these two standards.

My best guess is that it doesn't matter, because Google consider the two URLs identical. That might also be what's stated in the standards, but I'm not good at reading these, so I can't confirm nor deny that.

Using the the `xn--` format works. I haven't tried using Unicode characters to see if that also works.

Answer (score 0):

As your example contains a URI with characters NOT in the US-ASCII table, you will need to percent encode them.

Example from Bing:

```
Your URL:
http://www.domain.com/Ð¿Ð°Ð¿ÐºÐ°/ 

To Disallow: /Ð¿Ð°Ð¿ÐºÐ°/

Without Percent encoding (Not Compatible):
Disallow: /Ð¿Ð°Ð¿ÐºÐ°/

With Percent encoding (Compatile):
Disallow: /%D0%BF%D0%B0%D0%BF%D0%BA%D0%B0/
```

This [Bing blog post](https://blogs.bing.com/webmaster/2009/11/05/robots-speaking-many-languages/) may be of help.

For the XML sitemap, non-ASCII characters can be used but must be encoded to match the encoding readability of your server. See this [guide](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/35653?hl=en) by Google for a more detailed explanation with examples.

Comment: The question is if I can use non latin characters in the domain in my sitemap and in my robots.txt. But thanks for trying :)

Comment: @user1087110 Good point! I just edited my answer to provide more information on foreign characters in the `sitemap.xml`

Answer (score 0):

They must be ASCII encoded as follows:

- Domain name portion must be Punycoded: https://www.punycoder.com/
- Path portion must be URL encoded (percent encoded): https://www.urlencoder.io/